# MSSQL full outer join wrong output

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, full-outer-join

I am a newbie in MSSQL. I keep Tax Payers and Sale and Purchase invoices of them.

I want both purchase and sale Invoices together of a specific Tax Payer in the same row.
I tried to use full outer join in a stored procedure to retrieve the Invoices by day.
But it does not work as I want. This is what I've done so far:

```
CREATE PROC InvoiceByDay @InvoiceDate datetime AS
SELECT s.Tax_Payer_ID AS ID, 
  s.Sale_InvoiceID AS [Sale Invoice Number], 
  s.Sale_Total_Amount AS [Total Sale Amount], 
  p.Purchase_InvoiceID AS [Purchase Invoice Number], 
  p.Purchase_Total_Amount AS [Total Purchase Amount]
FROM Sale_Invoice s 
FULL OUTER JOIN Purchase_Invoice p
  ON s.Sale_Date=@InvoiceDate 
  and s.Tax_Payer_ID=p.Tax_Payer_ID 
  and s.Sale_Date=p.Purchase_Date
```

And this is the output:
[image: Output]

Even the second row is not in the specificated day, it is still on the list.What could be a good solution?Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

A `full outer join` keeps all records from both tables, even when there is no matching key.  I think you want to do the filtering *before* the join:

```
SELECT s.tax_payer_id          AS ID, 
       s.sale_invoiceid        AS [Sale Invoice Number], 
       s.sale_total_amount     AS [Total Sale Amount], 
       p.purchase_invoiceid    AS [Purchase Invoice Number], 
       p.purchase_total_amount AS [Total Purchase Amount] 
FROM (SELECT s.* 
      FROM sale_invoice s 
      WHERE s.sale_date = @InvoiceDate
     ) s FULL OUTER JOIN
     (SELECT p.* 
      FROM purchase_invoice p 
      WHERE p.purchase_date = @InvoiceDate
     ) p 
     ON s.tax_payer_id = p.tax_payer_id;
```

This should return all purchase and sales records on that date -- and only on that date -- even when there are no matches.

Comment: @Bar . . . That would suggest that there are no transactions on those dates.  One possibility is that some of the dates are really date/times with a time component and others are dates, so they do not match.  If this is a problem, you can cast all to `date` . . . `cast(p.purchase_date as date)` etc.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want the `s.Sale_Date=@InvoiceDate` in the WHERE clause, not the ON clause of the join. Also, since you are using a full join, you will need both sides of this condition as well so you need to add `OR p.Purchase_Date = @InvoiceDate` or you will not get any rows when there is no match in the left table (since `s.Sale_Date` will be NULL):

```
SELECT s.Tax_Payer_ID AS ID, 
  s.Sale_InvoiceID AS [Sale Invoice Number], 
  s.Sale_Total_Amount AS [Total Sale Amount], 
  p.Purchase_InvoiceID AS [Purchase Invoice Number], 
  p.Purchase_Total_Amount AS [Total Purchase Amount]
FROM Sale_Invoice s 
FULL OUTER JOIN Purchase_Invoice p
  ON s.Tax_Payer_ID=p.Tax_Payer_ID 
  and s.Sale_Date=p.Purchase_Date 
WHERE s.Sale_Date = @InvoiceDate 
OR p.Purchase_Date = @InvoiceDate
```

Answer (score 0):

The first part of your `ON` clause (i.e. `s.Sale_Date=@InvoiceDate`) should actually be in a `where` clause. You want to do something like:

```
FULL OUTER JOIN Purchase_Invoice p
  and s.Tax_Payer_ID=p.Tax_Payer_ID 
  and s.Sale_Date=p.Purchase_Date
WHERE s.Sale_Date=@InvoiceDate
```

Also, note that `FULL OUTER JOIN` will give you results for rows that don't have matching keys. If you only want records that had the same tax payer id and sale date in both tables, consider using `INNER JOIN` instead.